default-valued optional (boolean) parameter for a new command in tikz
I want to define a command for TikZ which has a default-valued optional parameter which is a Boolean, initially set to false.
I've looked around and have found:

xparse appears to be obsolete: https://ca.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf

I am very in experienced with the syntax used in Optional arguments in pgfkeys?, so don't know if it's a rabbit hole or not. At first glance, it seems overly complicated for the task, but I'm willing to use it if necessary.

I thought about using ifthenelse, but I have the suspicion that it's more natural to do it with TikZ syntax.


Here is an MWE using plain LaTeX commands. I'd like to achieve something similar to this: \mycommand[bool=false], or omit the false to leave it true.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\drawLines}{1} % 1 is true, 0 is false
\newcommand{\drawscope}{
% Draws a scope, with or without an axis.
\draw circle(1);
\fill circle(0.05);
\ifnum\drawLines=1
{
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
}
\fi{}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz \drawscope;
\end{document}



The package xparse is obsolote because it is built-in in the LaTeX lernel. Meaning the commands and almost all argument types are available out of the box (just like \newcommand is). Off-topic: Your syntax is a bit incorrect here, since \drawbox is not a TikZ-path so the ; is too much (but needed here for the brace-less \tikz command).

Why don't you just define a custom \if using \newif\ifdrawlines for example and then \drawlinestrue or \drawlinesfalse?

What do you want the optional argment to be? 1 and 0? I'd opt for a PGFKey that sets a custom \ifdrawlines and then the optional argment could just be [draw lines] or [don't draw lines] or whatever. Since it's a boolean, it might make more sense to use \drawscope and \drawscope* (this supported by the xparse part very well).

@JasperHabicht Part of the goal is to learn how to do it  for future commands too. In this instance I am using only one optional parameter, but I plan on making commands which may use several. Hence, it seems to make more sense to define optional parameters which can be called with \command[opt1,opt2=false,opt3=42,etc]

Here are a few possibilities (which are already outlined in the comments by @JasperHabicht and @Qrrbrbirlbel).
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\NewDocumentCommand\drawscopeLTCMD{s}
  {%
    \draw circle[radius=1];
    \fill circle[radius=0.05];
    \IfBooleanT{#1}
      {%
        \draw (0, -1) -- (0, 1);
        \draw (-1, 0) -- (1, 0);
      }%
  }

\newif\ifdrawLines
\pgfqkeys{/drawscope}{bool/.is if=drawLines}
\newcommand\drawscopePGFKEYS[1][]
  {%
    \pgfqkeys{/drawscope}{#1}%
    \draw circle[radius=1];
    \fill circle[radius=0.05];
    \ifdrawLines
      \draw (0, -1) -- (0, 1);
      \draw (-1, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \fi
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { drawscope } { unknown-value }
  { Unknown~ value~ '#1'. }
\NewDocumentCommand \drawscopeCUSTOM { o }
  {
    \draw circle[radius=1];
    \fill circle[radius=0.05];
    \IfValueT {#1}
      {
        \str_case:nnF
          {
            { true } { \draw (0, -1) -- (0, 1); \draw (-1, 0) -- (1, 0); }
            { false } {}
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { drawscope } { unknown-value } {#1} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawLines}{1} % 1 is true, 0 is false
\newcommand{\drawscope}{
% Draws a scope, with or without an axis.
\draw circle(1);
\fill circle(0.05);
\ifnum\drawLines=1
{
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
}
\fi{}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz \drawscope;
\tikz \drawscopeLTCMD;
\tikz \drawscopeLTCMD*;
\tikz \drawscopePGFKEYS[bool];
\tikz \drawscopePGFKEYS[bool=false];
\tikz \drawscopeCUSTOM;
\tikz \drawscopeCUSTOM[true];
\tikz \drawscopeCUSTOM[false];
\end{document}


Yes, the pgfkeys syntax does exactly what I want. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and providing an instructive example.

Since it's a boolean parameter, the closest and easiest would be a optional *, indicated by the s in the argument specification of \NewDocumentCommand.
We can test this argument with \IfBooleanT, \IfBooleanF and \IfBooleanTF. Since you don't want to do something in one instance either T or F can be used here.
The ; problem I've mentioned in a comment is firstly not a big problem and secondly not the point of your question but I've solved it here anyway by using the braced version of \tikz.
Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawscope}{s}{
  \draw circle[radius=1];
  \fill circle[radius=0.05];
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{
    \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\drawscope}
\tikz{\drawscope*}
\end{document}


Thank you for your response. Having reviewed the solutions, I think the pgfkeys syntax makes the most sense for my purposes, so I accepted that. It's good to know that there are other options available though, and it's also useful to know that xparse is just deprecated.
